# Custom UIView created by loadNibNamed:owner:options: leaks after removeFromSuperview

Tags: ios, uiview, memory-leaks, nib, loadnibnamed

I have application where I want to show my CustomView (inherited from UIView) with some content. But I don't need it at each point during runtime so I would like to create it and also delete it to avoid wasting with memory.

I have this view in separate nib file. And loading it with this code in viewController:

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self options:nil];

for (id object in arr) {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[MyCustomView class]])
        self.myCustomView = (MyCustomView *)object;
}  

[self.view addSubview:self.myCustomView];
```

myCustomView is property of viewController

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MyCustomView *myCustomView;
```

But in Instruments I can see that #Living is 3 (for example, when I call the code above three times), #Transitory is still 1 and #Overall is 4. It means MyCustomView leaks :( 
When I set `self.myCustomView = nil` it is useless :(

Could someone please help me to solve this leak? I'm using ARC.

Comment: I have same problem, did you find a solution?

/ Morten

Answer (score 0):

I think `[MyCustomView removeFromSuperview]` will do the job. :)